# Can I fetch file size using watchdog when it is being deleted?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-watchdog

I have created a python script for watching files changes in a folder. I can catch all events using default watchdog event listeners (`on_created`, `on_deleted` etc). I save the size of every new file in an array (`file_size_array`) and when a user deletes the file, I have to take out the size of that deleted file from `file_size_array` in order to have accurate behaviour.

So I tried fetching the size of that deleted file in "on_deleted" event but it throws `FileNotFoundError`. I also tried "on_any_event" method to catch deleted event and fetch the file size there but still it throws `FileNotFoundError`.

I tried this:

```
def on_deleted(self, event):
    print(os.path.getsize(event.src_path))
```

Also tried this:

```
def on_any_event(self, event):
    if event.event_type == "deleted":
        print(os.path.getsize(event.src_path))
```

But still get `FileNotFoundError`.

I would just like to fetch the size of file immediately after the deletion of file to remove its size from the `file_size_array`. I can't compare the whole `file_size_array` with the remaining files because the files are huge in quantity so I feel it would be an overkill. Probably a simple solution exists for this. Any ideas folks?

Comment: From what i see, the `event` raised does not contain information of file size. Also calling `os.path` after the file got deleted will obviously raise an error. Can't you just store the file names instead?

Comment: I have to do computation with file sizes. Is there anything else I should use to fetch file size instead of os.path?

Comment: You won't be able to fetch the size after deletion no matter what method you use. I would suggest you to store as `{filename:size}` so you can do the same thing upon deletion. If there are file size changes, it can still be caught by `on_modified` and you can update the file size.

Comment: Seems like a nice idea, but it would consume a lot of memory in my case, if I have no other choice than will go with it. My idea was to get the file size on on_any_event method, I suppose that is called before on_delete event handler so it would fetch the file size. Guess I am messing up the event cycle in my head.